# Chrome not drawing specific jpg image in canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, jpeg

I'm trying to draw an image in a canvas. This works in Firefox but not in Chrome 49.

```
context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/3/

Image link: http://www.boardgame-online.com/img/stackoverflow_chrome_test.jpg

Something seems to be wrong with the image. We tried coping the image in another jpg that did draw, and then it worked. But what is wrong with this image?

Comment: I am using Chrome 51. It works in my browser.

Comment: That's interesting. I could not find a bug report about this issue.

Comment: Definitely a bug in Chrome 49. Can be reproduced across multiple devices for that version. Notably: the image loads correctly in an <img> tag. If loaded in an <img> tag before the <canvas> code is executed, it works. However, when loaded directly into the <canvas> after its onload event, it will result in Chrome thinking the image is blank. If you put it in an <img> tag afterwards, that will also be blank. Chrome is messing up for sure in version 49. Reason for this? Unknown.

Comment: Open your console, allow warnings : "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.boardgame-online.com/img/stackoverflow_chrome_test.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS." probably a cause of your issue.

Comment: @Kaiido That seems to be an unrelated issue, but thanks for pointing it out. The jsfiddle needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Dysprosium, yep, just tried with the non-secured jsfiddle and it's still happening. However, the same exact code from localhost server works, and calling https images from jsfiddle also does work. Maybe related to the iframe, maybe related to something else. According to Naman Nehra, it's fixed anyway and the problem seems more specific than  "Chrome not drawing jpg image in canvas" which would have been noticed long before this question grown in OP's mind.

Comment: Have you tried using the code with the exact image with localhost?

Comment: @Anorionil, yep, definitely. Also, it seems clear from comments here that you found a bug, but that this bug was found by Chrome guys before since they fixed it in next versions. So I'm not sure we can provide any help.

Comment: It's a cross domain /cross origin issue I think ...replace the image with "https://www.google.ro/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" and it works.  Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/2/

Comment: The image is malformed in some way that chrome can not seem to decode. Resaving the image and it loaded just fine on chrome 49. I dont have the appropriate utility at hand to see the precise error but will have a look when back at my main computer.

Comment: Add  Access-Control-Allow-Origin * to your headers when serving the image.

Comment: @Iansen it is not a cross origin problem. Chrome will not display the image no matter where it comes from. The error is either in the image or with chrome.

Comment: @Blindman67, then why can I draw it on localhost and not in jsfiddle.net ? Not sure it is an image corrupt thing either. Most definitely a bug : http://jsfiddle.net/jfrjc4eg/ see how the original image disappears when parsed by context ?

Comment: @Kaiido It would not draw on my chrome from localhost, file system, or original domain.(via injected script) It is to early to conclude it is a bug, the image may be malformed with all but chrome handling the error to spec. Without knowing what is wrong it is but guess work. Chrome does return an image that is the correct size, it is just has no pixels set.

Comment: Changed link to https https://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/3/

Comment: The problem is the `canvas.height = 400;` line... It works up to `height = 219`. After it breaks. https://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/6/ So file corrupt on this line + a chrome bug in v49 ?

Comment: I've also tested with the height and width. If you set width = 398 and height  = 165. increasing either one of them will break the fiddle.

Comment: @Kaiido Tried your fiddle but did not solve it for me.

Comment: @Blindman67 ah! which os ? I'm on osx 10.9. And it's not a solve, it's a found more closely where the bug lies. http://i.stack.imgur.com/IHqcx.png

Comment: @Anorionil and you can see the image in https://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/6/ ?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, if I increase the height to 220, it fails.

Comment: Current Chrome beta on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved in Chrome 50. When I open the JSFiddle in my updated Chrome, the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is not an answer, all the cheers to [@kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)**

**Working example:**

```js
var backgroundImage = new Image();

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 100;
    
backgroundImage.onload = function(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
 context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
}
backgroundImage.src = "http://www.boardgame-online.com/img/stackoverflow_chrome_test.jpg";

$("#test").append(canvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

**Not Working example:**

```js
var backgroundImage = new Image();

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
    
backgroundImage.onload = function(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
 context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
}
backgroundImage.src = "http://www.boardgame-online.com/img/stackoverflow_chrome_test.jpg";

$("#test").append(canvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: no running from [http://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/kp5otnyu/1/) does the same thing, the problem is elsewhere :

Comment: working for us too with the stacksnippet origin... try the link in my comment.

Comment: yep, it's not working, so it's not a chrome problem, it a jsfiddle policy, if you can access the image with https you can test it.

Comment: ... yes it's a chrome bug... try to run the code in your console from [this same exact page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082257/chrome-not-drawing-specific-jpg-image-in-canvas#comment-59813841), you'll get the same result. If it works in any other browsers and in any other versions, it's more likely to be a browser bug.

Comment: It works in the stackoverflow snippet for me... But it doesn't seem to be related to https, I updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: Indeed is something related to chrome and canvas width and height, weird stuff happening, in my example one example is working one not, who has the wisdom to help us?

Comment: It seems to be related to height. If you increase the height, it fails. So probably it will also fail on stackoverflow if you increase the height.

Comment: sorry man, I wasn't in the comment's section, so I don't sow what you said there

Comment: I can delete the answer case is not an answer and report this crap to chrome

Comment: Maybe its indeed better to delete the answer so that people know there's still an issue?